# unity - button is not intractable, but still works

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a button and I set it's intractable to false( unchecked ). But It still works. I mean it is grayed out but I can click on it completely and it works and all functions act.
I don't know what is wrong.

Also I added an EventTrigger and a PointerClick To It. When intractable is turned off and I removing the EventTrigger during the runtime, the problem will solve. I think maybe that EventTrigger or PointerClick has another intractable option. maybe I should turn that off. Any Idea...?

Comment: Are you setting not intractable from code or Editor?

Comment: I setting from code.

Comment: Then show the code. It seems to me that you are setting the wrong button. I suggest setting it from the Editor, finding out if the problem is still there then tell us the result but you must post that code.

Comment: TBH No idea what the Interactable property is supposed to do, it doesn't work. Instead, turn off Raycast Target in any Image scripts attached to the button.

Comment: @Programmer The code is very big and complex and I can't put it here.

Comment: @Absinthe I know I can turn off Raycast Target but It is kind of erasing the problem.

Comment: Ok I tested something. During the code, I was added an EventTrigger and a PointerClick to it. ( that won't appears in inspector? ) Now when the intractable is turned off, I removed the EventTrigger component and then it worked and clicking on the button didn't take effect. I think maybe that PointerClick or maybe that EventTrigger has another intractability that needs to turn off.  Any idea ...?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use button OnClickListner, and Event trigger would work if you have raycast target as checked on the image or text or any ui object. uncheck that and it shall work :)